# loading div not working on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

my html:

```
<span id="loading"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Please Wait</span>
```

```
#loading{display:none;}
```

my js:

```
var Progressajax = false;

$(function() {
  $(".commentmoreview").click(function(){

    if(Progressajax) return;
    Progressajax = true;

    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr("id");

    $('#loading').show();

    var value = $('.pagecont'+id).val();
    var info = 'id='+id+'&pagecont='+value;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php-comments/php/loadmorecomments.php",
      data: info,
      success: function(data){
        $('#loading').hide();
          Progressajax = false;
        value = parseInt(value)+parseInt(5);
        $('.pagecont'+id).val(value);
        $(data).hide().prependTo('#loadmorecomments'+id).fadeIn(1000);
        //$('#loadmorecomments'+id).prepend(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

what is wrong that loading span is not working?

thank you friends!

Comment: Can you fiddle your code?

Comment: So basically you want to show some `loading message` whenever you're making any ajax call, is it?

Comment: So you shouldn't add your code in comment, simply you may edit your question and update your code over there.

Comment: yes, i want to show the loading span. but it is not working. this loading span css is a simple display:none

Comment: If you remove the display: none does it appear? (without running other code).

Comment: yeah! without display none its ok

Comment: It may happen that ajax call is completing so fast that image is getting hide imagiately after showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to show loader image while making ajax calls is using [Ajax Global Events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
  $("#loading").show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
  $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Comment: need to put it inside  $.ajax({ ? or before it?

Comment: just inside your <script> tag

Answer (score 0):

can you change

```
$('#loading').show();
```

to

```
$('#loading').attr("display","block");
```

and try to use it like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php-comments/php/loadmorecomments.php",
  data: info,
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#loading').attr("display","block");
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('#loading').attr("display","none");
      Progressajax = false;
    value = parseInt(value)+parseInt(5);
    $('.pagecont'+id).val(value);
    $(data).hide().prependTo('#loadmorecomments'+id).fadeIn(1000);
    //$('#loadmorecomments'+id).prepend(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: there will be no difference in using `.show()` and changing `display` attribute.

Comment: thank you! it works! the problem was in another js that was interfering in this loading div.